# How to avoid jquery library from effecting my css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with nav buttons and dropdowns with a photo slider below it which uses requires the inclusion of `jquery.min.js`.

When I include jQuery it effects my CSS preventing my dropdowns from expanding open.

```
<div id="sticky_navigation">
  <ul class="menumix">
    <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/home_icon.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php">VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LANGUAGE<span class="dc-mega-icon"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="setcookies.php?id=5">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="setcookies.php?id=6">Malayalam</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul> 
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='slider/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <div id="slider_main">     
  <div id="fluid_container">
    <div class="camera_wrap" id="camera_wrap_1">
      <div data-src="slider/slides/">
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: hi can you post a fiddle demo.

Comment: jQuery doesn't do anything unless you tell it to in your scripts. It doesn't modify any CSS by itself.

Comment: If i remove that jquery library then my dropdown will work properly. Recently i changed my slider. Dropdown was working well earlier but now with this new jquery library it is not working

Comment: jQuery isn't bootstrap. It won't mess up your CSS unless you tell it too.

Comment: I have not come up with any solutions till now. Any more suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding some simple css code for the dropdown
i.e

```
ul li:hover ul
 {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Earlier the dropdown was working without this code but now after adding the new slider i need to add this additional code to show the dropdwon. Thank you all who gave some idea's to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some CSS path conflicts between drop down component and slider component.

You may be able to temporarily fix this issue by modifying some elements' ID, slightly modify HTML structure, but I highly recommend you to read components' source code if available to see what kind of CSS configuration they are using.

Another way to quickly confirm what's wrong is to open browser web developer tools (Eg: Chrome's built in web developer tools) to see what kind of CSS properties of your components are being unexpectedly inherited, and the Javascript console of the tool might give you the information of the potentially happening Javascript error.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi can you just cross check my jquery file to see whether any code can conflict the top manu div. Download link is http://www.freefilehosting.net/jquerymin_2

Comment: You should rely on a CDN hosted copy of jQuery instead. And you can easily compare two files together — many tools are available, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Certain jQuery UI plugins, do in fact, add classes and attributes to your HTML. This is absolutely necessary if you want to take advantage of the convenience and elegance that jQuery provides for you.

Since the plugin or module is in fact adding attributes and styles to your HTML, you should either (1) re-write the plugin avoiding the jQuery library completely. (2) Fork the plugin, and alter the HTML attribute alteration code and pick symbols that fit your needs and constraints.

Comment: @ self i tried to fix the issue by adding z-index to very high value to the menu dropdown css. But the dropdown is not yet displaying.